# Clear input field using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, livechat

I'm building a live chat-app and having trouble with clearing the input field. After form is submitted, I want the input field to be cleared. I changed the state to an empty sdtate but not working at all.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import './ChatRoom.css'
import { ChatContext } from '../ChatContext'
import ScrollToBottom from 'react-scroll-to-bottom'


const ChatRoom = () => {
    const { userName, setUserName } = useContext(ChatContext)
    const { roomCode, setRoomCode } = useContext(ChatContext)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([])

    const handleMessage = (e) => {
        var newMessage = e.currentTarget.value
        // console.log(newMessage)
        setMessage(newMessage)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Message submitted')
        setMessage("")
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="top-container">
                <h2>123</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="chat-container">
            {/* {renderChat()} */}
            <h1>hello</h1>
            </div>
            <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" onChange={handleMessage} className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Type your message here..."/>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mb-2">Send</button>
            </form>
        </>
        
    )
}


export default ChatRoom;
```

Comment: Henry you should add value to the input field to handle as a controlled component `<input type="text" onChange={handleMessage}  value={message} ... "/>`

Comment: I don't see the message state being used in the input field at all. I guess thats why you don't see it clear out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using an [uncontrolled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). Try setting `value={message}` on the input.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to control the input field with React. Add a `value` prop to it:

```js
<input type="text" onChange={handleMessage} className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Type your message here..." value={message}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add value attribute and bind message state field as shown below.

```
<input type="text" onChange={handleMessage} value={message} className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Type your message here..."/>
```